# Change the color attribute of a mulitline layer

Tags: python, shapefile, features, color

I'm very new in world of the shapefiles, i have a code that add point in a multiline layer, but when i open with ArcGis each layer have a different color, and i want that all the layer have the same color automatically. I have this code but it isn't work.

How i can fix it?

```
def create_line(coords,scale):
    line=ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
    for coord in coords:
        coord[0]=scale[4]+(coord[0]*scale[0])
        coord[1]=scale[5]+(scale[3]*coord[1])
        line.AddPoint(coord[0],coord[1])
    return line
```

.....

```
            new_shape=str('Vias '+`key`+`z`)

            new_shape= new_shape + '.shp'

            #Crear una nueva fuente de datos y capa para los elementos detectados
            if os.path.exists(new_shape):
                driver.DeleteDataSource(new_shape)
            ds= driver.CreateDataSource(new_shape)
            print "El shapefile creado es " + new_shape

            if ds is None:
                print 'No puede crear el shapefile'
                sys.exit(1)

            #Crea una capa de elemntos
            layer=ds.CreateLayer(new_shape, geom_type=ogr.wkbMultiLineString)

            #Añade un campo id al shapefile de salida para los elementos encontrados
            fieldDefn=ogr.FieldDefn('id', ogr.OFTString)
            layer.CreateField(fieldDefn)
            z=z+1
            multiline=ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbMultiLineString)


        line=create_line(data[key][key1],scale)

        multiline.AddGeometry(line)
        h=0
        if line:
            featureDefn=layer.GetLayerDefn()

            #Crea un nuevo rasgo
            feature= ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
            feature.SetGeometry(multiline)
            feature.SetField('id',h+1)
            feature.SetColor(QtGui.QColor('blue'))

            #Añade el rasgo de la capa de salida
            layer.CreateFeature(feature)

            h=h+1
```